# C# string format unknown size

Tags: c#, linq, string.format

Let's say I have the following string:

```
string postData = "state={2}&country={3}&geolocation={0}&city={1}";
```

And I have another list of strings. Its size could be in this case 4 at most.
I'm trying to create a method which replaces the numbers in my postData variable, depending on the list size. Something like the following method:

```
private string UnknownSizeStringFormat(string postData, params string[] stringsToReplace)
{
    return string.format(postData, stringsToReplace);
}
```

The above method works **as long as the list's size is 4**. The thing is, on the first call, my list's size could be smaller than 4, so if it's 0 for example, I would like to replace each number inside the brackets with an empty string. My return value should be:

```
"state=&country=&geolocation=&city="
```

If its size is one, and the first member in the list is "21,27" my return string should be:

```
"state=&country=&geolocation=21,27&city="
```

And so on...
I could use a loop or a Regular Expression for this purpose but I've been wondering if there is a better way, a Linq solution perhaps? What I do know is how many numbers postData could have at most, which in my case is 4.
**Again, I could do that with a loop or a Regular Expression, but I'm trying to make it as short as possible**

**Edit: The postData string could vary. That was just an example. Its size or content could be different**

Comment: I don't know how your list is populated, but I would think a simple solution could be to add blank strings to the list for the missing items. Not saying it's a great solution or that it'll even work in your specific case, but it's something to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I do know is how many numbers postData could have at most

Then how about this:

```
static string UnknownSizeStringFormat(string format, int maxArgs, params object[] args)
{
    Array.Resize(ref args, maxArgs);
    return string.Format(format, args);
}
```

so you can use:

```
string postData = "state={2}&country={3}&geolocation={0}&city={1}";
var result = UnknownSizeStringFormat(postData, 4);
```

Comment: I like this solution!

Comment: Short and simple, I love it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to write in C#6, then I would suggest you the following quick solution

Define a class that has as properties the parameters you refer to and ovveride the `ToString` method in a such a way to return the url you want.

```
public class CustomUrl
{
    public string State {get;set;}
    public string Country { get;set;}
    public string Geolocation {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}

    public ovveride string ToString() =>
        $"state={State}&country={Country}&geolocation={Geolocation}&city={City}";      

}
```

you can use it as:

```
var customUrl = new CustomUrl
{
   Geolocation = "21,27";
}
```

Then calling `customUrl.ToString()`, you would get:

```
"state=&country=&geolocation=21,27&city="
```

While creating another customer url as:

```
var customUrl = new CustomUrl();
```

and the calling `customUrl.ToString()` you would get:

```
"state=&country=&geolocation=&city="
```

If you are not allowed to write in C#, you have to modify a bit the class's definition, like below:

```
public class CustomUrl
{
    public string State {get;set;}
    public string Country { get;set;}
    public string Geolocation {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}

    public ovveride string ToString()
    {
        retrun string.Format("state={0}&country={1}&geolocation={2}&city={3}",State,Country,Geolocation,City);      
    }
}
```

However, the *best solution* can be found at [Named Formats Redux](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/14/named-formats-redux.aspx/), the Henri formatter. If you implement this, you could call it as an extension method, like below:

```
var template = "state={state}&country={country}&geolocation={geo}&city={city}";
var customUrl = template.HenriFormat(new { geo = "21,72"});
```

The reason I say that this is the best solution is the fact that you would implement it once and you could use it anywhere, without have to implement a custom class for a case like the above.

Comment: ...and if he's not allowed to write C#6, he could do the same exact thing but with `String.Format()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
private string UnknownSizeStringFormat(string postData, params string[] stringsToReplace)
{
    string[] temp = { "", "", "", "" };
    Array.ConstrainedCopy(stringsToReplace, 0, temp, 0, stringsToReplace.Length);
    return string.format(postData, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adjusting your postData based on stringsToReplace.Length. You can use a switch/case method to control this. This is non-tested code, so please use with debug to verify.

```
string postData = "state={2}&country={3}&geolocation={0}&city={1}";

private string UnknownSizeStringFormat(string postData, params string[] stringsToReplace)
{
    switch(stringsToReplace.Length){
        case 0:
        postData = "state={0}&country={0}&geolocation={0}&city={0}";
        break;
        case 1:
        postData = "state={0}&country={0}&geolocation={1}&city={0}";
        break;
        case 2:
        postData = "state={2}&country={0}&geolocation={1}&city={0}";
        break;
        case 3:
        postData = "state={2}&country={3}&geolocation={1}&city={0}";
        break;
        case 4:
        postData = "state={2}&country={3}&geolocation={1}&city={4}";
        break;
    return string.format(postData, String.Empty, stringsToReplace);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, I probably wasn't. The postData string could vary

Comment: A switch in these cases is just useless code duplication

Comment: @Skatz1990 "And I have another list of strings. Its size could be 4 at most."

Comment: In this case, sorry!